# Cosine Similarities are either -1 or 1 but I need them to be bet 0 and 1

Tags: python, mean, cosine-similarity

I was trying to get better results in a simililarity measurement of word vectors. 
My first attempt was, to sum the word vectors of one data set up and then compare these. This worked perfectly and I got cosine similarities between 0.0 and 1.0. 
Next, I wanted to try the mean instead of the sum and now I get only -1 or 1 as cosine similarity. I used exactly the same code to normalise the vectors and calculate the similarities:

```
#get mean of two data sets
data_set_1 = numpy.mean(x, axis=0, dtype=numpy.float64)
data_set_2 = numpy.mean(y, axis=0, dtype=numpy.float64)

#normalise and similarities
dot = numpy.dot(data_set_1, data_set2)
norm_1 = numpy.linalg.norm(data_set_1)
norm_2 = numpy.linalg.norm(data_set_2)
cosine = dot / (norm_1 * norm_2)
```

I really don't understand what is happening and would appreciate any explanation and help.
Thanks in advance!

one sample from x:

```
array([-0.04613502, -0.374053  ,  1.0891489 ,  1.061047  , -1.741486  ,
    3.190435  , -0.17060003, -2.309955  , -0.86257803, -1.6470661 ,
    0.87436306, -2.5333838 , -3.656079  , -0.30654398,  0.325557  ,
   -3.331116  ,  1.2278409 , -0.40595996, -2.154634  , -0.22806   ,
    1.401475  , -2.332394  ,  0.278537  ,  1.1624339 ,  2.384433  ,
   -2.408423  ,  0.45369   , -1.732967  ,  0.09182203,  0.12795903,
   -1.4582571 , -1.2875669 ,  1.023271  ,  1.042664  , -1.237168  ,
   -0.512995  ,  1.8300351 , -1.193877  ,  0.976277  ,  0.102451  ,
    0.26501298, -0.52354795,  0.9597741 ,  0.448617  ,  1.157445  ,
    1.7488811 ,  1.8456432 ,  1.90311   , -3.27624   ,  1.6807759 ,
   -0.685457  , -0.972376  , -1.3833561 , -2.4522452 ,  0.44415504,
   -1.187554  ,  0.00743097,  1.097488  , -2.288848  ,  0.693663  ,
    0.459846  ,  0.95192504,  2.324767  , -2.36057   , -0.85801494,
   -0.41272697,  1.4259889 , -1.4683809 , -1.1142931 ,  3.3002188 ,
   -0.498667  ,  2.0547547 , -2.744741  ,  0.263174  , -4.105273  ,
    0.48422903, -1.700531  ,  0.913477  , -0.056857  , -2.2725968 ,
   -0.01261299,  3.881847  ,  2.155569  , -0.892547  ,  0.93188393,
    2.5996652 , -1.15262   , -3.3539262 ,  0.42770797, -0.67410505,
   -2.2817628 , -0.41883698,  1.7624649 , -0.539206  , -1.9789242 ,
    1.3393929 ,  0.21492898,  0.37769097, -0.18817309, -0.070536  ,
   -1.261518  ,  0.694033  ,  0.33215603, -2.5891778 ,  1.069283  ,
   -2.6675131 ,  0.380206  ,  1.6508749 ,  0.53682804, -0.01185702,
   -2.382148  ,  0.721966  , -0.10766903,  0.710052  ,  2.25537   ,
    0.629406  ,  1.000657  ,  0.487805  , -0.68280804, -1.4945159 ,
    0.666168  , -1.740483  ,  0.24742898, -1.137784  , -0.8557059 ,
    1.057287  ,  0.499617  , -0.18203099,  0.726008  ,  0.294519  ,
    1.6262889 , -0.82582104,  1.2082001 , -1.0171441 , -1.349803  ,
    0.656978  ,  2.041149  , -0.903942  , -2.338575  ,  2.105005  ,
    0.934928  , -0.253907  ,  2.440666  ,  1.13323   , -1.501967  ,
    3.3456352 , -0.20194799, -0.51617   ,  0.11740598,  1.541899  ,
   -1.9015999 , -0.26909196,  0.98262006,  1.0990311 , -1.420755  ,
    3.4223778 ,  1.476057  ,  1.031273  , -1.288164  ,  1.364767  ,
   -0.369442  , -0.126815  ,  0.05568901, -0.135142  , -3.809312  ,
    0.821946  ,  0.08596402, -2.083506  ,  2.4171226 , -0.15828298,
   -1.053609  , -2.703516  ,  2.763613  , -0.06973301, -1.6185119 ,
   -0.66888297, -2.6508129 ,  0.832166  ,  1.5613132 , -2.3090322 ,
    1.252052  ,  0.639106  , -2.109521  ,  0.976087  ,  1.901486  ,
    0.23191603,  1.683491  ,  1.823172  , -1.300951  , -0.305817  ,
   -0.207237  , -0.544769  ,  0.999225  , -0.429891  , -1.530632  ,
    0.35141605,  0.655623  , -2.129103  , -0.04165304,  2.108568  ,
    0.07581904, -2.039279  , -1.000134  ,  0.868666  ,  1.914941  ,
    1.1933999 ,  0.23656599,  0.114346  , -0.18701899, -0.558287  ,
    1.555753  , -0.19221498,  0.536237  ,  1.248544  ,  2.515396  ,
   -1.5476761 , -0.956198  , -1.092072  , -2.3972921 ,  0.22388999,
    0.99310994, -0.22812304, -0.28389892, -2.5080059 ,  1.0636451 ,
    2.075475  , -0.71541995, -0.9618629 , -1.780458  , -0.467053  ,
   -0.626879  , -0.499579  ,  0.47822097, -0.07844701,  1.920962  ,
    1.670298  , -1.14183   ,  0.09302497, -1.776707  ,  1.7554679 ,
    0.292584  ,  0.55246603, -1.051265  ,  2.050335  ,  1.495105  ,
   -1.107776  ,  0.46003202, -3.3028882 , -1.248842  , -1.6026751 ,
   -0.798018  , -3.159801  , -2.717463  , -0.814624  ,  0.43029997,
   -1.67419   , -1.92975   , -2.826171  ,  3.885695  , -0.232862  ,
   -2.473109  ,  0.39019704,  1.52716   ,  0.1485    ,  1.2837529 ,
   -1.2407081 ,  0.18983305,  2.3301609 , -1.103073  , -0.36056796,
    0.95535696,  1.9529209 ,  0.340872  ,  0.88583004,  2.7519207 ,
   -0.32049602,  2.1213899 , -2.056772  ,  0.645749  ,  1.136208  ,
   -1.333711  , -0.68612206, -3.344446  ,  0.23510504, -2.16575   ,
   -0.621901  ,  0.25076202,  0.17458501, -1.154155  , -0.13617599,
    1.280092  ,  0.823536  , -1.315633  ,  3.0988638 ,  0.536109  ,
   -1.804625  , -1.059263  , -1.315307  ,  1.33476   , -3.209944  ],
  dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: what are `x` & `y`?

Comment: you are defining data_set_1 twice. Is this a typo?

Comment: x and y are lists of word vectors

Comment: yes, it was a typo, thanks :)

Comment: could you post a sample of x and y?

Comment: sure, I did that above